# Netbeans run doesnt deploy ear maven on glassfish

Tags: maven, netbeans, deployment, glassfish, ear

Netbeans 8.2, glassfish 5

In my maven EAR proyect, when I clean+build, it generates an EAR file. If I add this file manually to my glassfish (via glassfish console) it deploys OK and run the application.

Added glassfish to netbeans, but when click run on glassfish service, server starts, but doesnt deploy nothing. EAR file generates OK but glassfish doesnt deploy it.

My POM file in the EAR project (REMOVED SOME DEPENDENCIES AND MODULES TO SHORT IT):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>      
    <artifactId>b2btravel.ear.deploy</artifactId>    
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>B2B ear deploy</name>
    <description>B2B Travel WEB-EAR deply</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>b2btravel</groupId>
        <artifactId>b2btravel</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.11</version>        
    </parent>    


   <dependencies>      


            <!-- INTERNAL BUSINESS -->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>b2btravel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>b2btravel.business</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>ejb</type>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                    <groupId>b2btravel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>b2btravel.web.bck</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>


            <!-- EXTERNAL -->
    </dependencies>


    <build>     
        <plugins>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.ear.plugin}</version>               
                        <goals>
                                <goal>generate-application-xml</goal>
                                <goal>ear</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <version>7</version>
                            <applicationId>${application.web.id}</applicationId>
                            <applicationName>${application.web.name}</applicationName>
                            <displayName>${application.web.display.name}</displayName>
                            <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
                            <tempFolder>${project.build.directory}/${ear.web.file.name}</tempFolder>
                            <workDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${ear.web.file.name}/work</workDirectory>
                            <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                            <!-- If I want maven to generate the application.xml, set this to 
                                    true -->
                            <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                            <modules>
                                    <!-- WEB MODULES -->
                                    <jarModule>
                                            <groupId>b2btravel</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>b2btravel.web</artifactId>
                                            <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                                            <bundleFileName>b2btravel.web.jar</bundleFileName>
                                            <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>
                                    </jarModule>
                                    <webModule>
                                            <groupId>b2btravel</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>b2btravel.web.bck</artifactId>
                                            <bundleFileName>b2btravel.web.bck.war</bundleFileName>
                                            <contextRoot>/bck</contextRoot>
                                    </webModule>                                   
                                    <ejbModule>
                                            <groupId>b2btravel</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>b2btravel.business</artifactId>
                                            <bundleFileName>b2btravel.business.jar</bundleFileName>
                                    </ejbModule>                                  
                            </modules>
                            <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                                    </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <finalName>${ear.web.file.name}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It's worth spending 2 minutes verifying that you can create and deploy an EAR project created using the NetBeans wizard: [1] **File > New Project... > Maven > Enterprise Application** ... to create new EAR/EJB/Web App. Be sure to set **Server** to **Glassfish 5**. [2] For the "...ear"  project that is created: **{select project} > Properties > Run**. [3] Your app will be deployed to Glassfish 5 and run. [4] A _Hello World!_ web page should open in the browser. If not then there is an issue with your NetBeans and/or Glassfish configuration.

Comment: This works, i think the real problem is a maven configuration in this proyect, have to investigate, because this is a huge old proyect

Thank you

Comment: OK, in that case I agree that you should focus on the Maven configuration, though it will be tricky since you are not getting any error. Check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) in case some issue is being logged there, but does not appear in the Glassfish log.